# Getting liked photos through facebook fql results in OAuthException

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Up until a few days ago, this query used to give me a list of (some of) the photos I liked:

```
$params = array(
    'method' => 'fql.multiquery',
    'queries' => '{
        "objects" : "SELECT object_id FROM like WHERE user_id = me() LIMIT 500",                
        "likes" : "SELECT object_id, owner, src_big, src_big_width, src_big_height, link, caption, created, like_info FROM photo WHERE object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM #objects)",
        }'
    );
```

Now all I'm getting in return is

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 1
  }
}
```

The permissions I got are read_stream, user_likes, user_photos and friend_photos. But I tried it with all possible permissions, still the same error. Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: Well, seems it was just a facebook glitch. Results are back to normal.